# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate with spring in my maven project. This is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mod.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Services</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.5.6</sl4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Configuration which allows JUnit tests to be placed in the same folder as java files
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
        <!-- Configuration which allows configuration files (such as xml files) to be placed in the same folder as java files
        <resources>
           <resource>
             <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</directory>
           </resource>
         </resources> -->
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        **********************************************************************
        ** SPRING DEPENDENCIES **
        ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
        ** POSTGRES DEPENDENCIES **
        ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>8.3-603.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
        ** HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES **
        ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
        ** JAVAX PERSISTENCE **
        ********************************************************************** -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- **********************************************************************
        ** OTHER DEPENDENCIES **
        ********************************************************************** -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
        ** TEST DEPENDENCIES
        ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my DAO class

```
public class Task_Impl implements Task_Interface {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionfactory;
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void createTask(Task task) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().save(task);
        System.out.println("Task created in database");


    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTask() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is my Dispatcher Servlet (HelloWeb-servlet.xml)

```
   xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring" 

   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="org.mod.com.Prime"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="task_impl_bean" class="org.mod.Prime.DAO.Implementation.Task_Impl">

</bean>

<bean id="sessionfactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses" value="org.mod.Prime.Data.Task"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/newdatabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="P@ssword"/>
</bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

  <bean id="txManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionfactory">
         <ref local="sessionfactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

When I try to run the project, I am getting the following error

```
Error creating bean with name 'task_impl_bean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.mod.Prime.DAO.Implementation.Task_Impl.sessionfactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
```

The main root cause is

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
```

As  you can see in my pom file I have included the hibernate jars. I dont know whats the exact error. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Wow, this is a lot of code. Have you narrowed down the problem at all?  If possible, consolidate the code snippets only to relevant parts and better explain your error, as well as whatever you've done to determine the issue. The community may close your question otherwise.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I have now consolidated my code

Answer (score 2):

This is dynamic class loading while Bean init! DTD entity Resolver is used while parsing the Spring Bean class while loading into the container. I think the version of your Hibernate is not compatible with your framework and code! Why are you using different hibernate-annotations version?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Are you sure that your Hibernate version is compatible with your Spring framework? Try to change the versions, also check your JVM version you are using to run the Spring server!

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the dataSourceBean before the sessionFactory

```
<bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/newdatabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="P@ssword"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionfactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses" value="org.mod.Prime.Data.Task"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```